# change link thickness of link d3 tree on button click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using a very common collapsible d3 tree layout. I have button that supposedly changes the thinckness of the Links between two nodes. I want a smooth transition that increases the link thickness. I tried the following code, but it does not work. In short on button click i am calling an update(root) and inside trying to update the link,

```js
 var linkUpdate = link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

 linkUpdate
   .style("stroke-width", "10px");
```

Rest of the update method is same as this code here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Thank You.

Comment: Please describe "does not work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call an update. Just perform the transition on the link itself when yoy click on the button. See below:

```
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke-width", "10px");
```